# Elementor Custom Widget Color Control, get value as string in settings

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I try to get the color of the color-control as a string. If I choose the color on the right side at the color-picker, everything works fine.

[image]
But

If I use the predefined colors on the left, the color is not updated in the content_template-method (or by the render-method in frontend), but it is shown in the right-side symbol of the color-control. If I click the color-symbol, the color is shown by the content_template method.

[image]

If I try selecting predefined colors twice, the default value is used by the content_template-method or the render()
This are the register-controlls(), render() and content_template() methods.

```
    protected function register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
                'color_to_show_section',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Farbe zum aussuchen', 'elementor-as-gmap-widget' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );
        $this->add_control(
            'title',
            [
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Title', 'textdomain' ),
                'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Enter your title', 'textdomain' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'landscape_color',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__( 'Color', 'elementor-as-gmap-widget' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::COLOR,
                'default' =>    '#ff00ff' ,
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();



    }


    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        ?>
            <h1> <?php echo $settings['title'] ?></h1>
            <p>Die Farbe: <?php echo $settings['landscape_color'] ?></p>
        <?php
    }


    protected function content_template() {
        ?>
            <h1>{{{settings.title}}}</h1>
            <p>Die Farbe: {{{settings.landscape_color }}}</p>
        <?php
    }
```

All examples and documentations are about using the color-control to set styles in css, so I wonder, if it is even possible, to get the color as string. But since the normal color-picker works, I think it is possible.
Thanks